# Wolfram|alpha comparing country sizes

Tags: wolfram-alpha

By inputting

> [Portugal shape area, China shape area](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Portugal+shape+area%2C+China+shape+area)

to Wolfram|alpha I can get two country shapes, but how can I get them on top of each other at the same scale? The output I'm looking for is what you get from [Mapfight](http://mapfight.appspot.com/).

Comment: Are you trying to do this from within WolframAlpha? What are you looking for that's different from a [Portugal v China Mapfight](http://mapfight.appspot.com/pt-vs-cn/portugal-china-size-comparison)?

Comment: Yes, within WolframAlpha. I'd like to use WolframAlpha's shapes as they are significantly more detailed than Mapfight's. For example, South Korea vs. Taiwan [mapfight](http://mapfight.appspot.com/tw-vs-kr/taiwan-south-korea-size-comparison) and [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=south+korea+shape%2C+taiwan+shape).

Answer (score 2):

W|A can evaluate some "arithmetic expressions" composed of property values of multiple entities.  Some examples include

- [Portugal / China area](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Portugal+%2F+China+area)
- [NYC + Chicago population](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NYC+%2B+Chicago+population)
- [Obama - Mao Zedong height](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NYC+%2F+Chicago+population)
- [(earth population / moon surface area  )](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28earth+population+%2F+moon+surface+area++%29)

To compare same property of two entities, doing division and/or subtraction seem the way to go.